# How do i make a dropdown list and have content change when selected - my content is a jquery accordion?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

How do i make a dropdown list and have content change when selected - my content is a jquery accordion?

I have a list of jobs and description in the accordion but i would like to categorize these jobs by adding some sort of dropdown or something to that sort.  So when you select one category (ex creative jobs), it only shows the jobs in that category. Must be able to support the jquery accordion.

Thanks :)

Comment: Can we see some of your markup, please?

Answer (score 1):

```
<select id="someid">
<option value="1">one</option>
<option value="2">two/option>
<option value="3">three</option>
<option value="4">four</option>
</select>
<p>change goes here and put it inside your accordion content tab</p>
```

script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#someid').change(function(){
   $('p').html($(this).text());
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the onchange="" event in your select element, or let jQuery handle this by element id / class / name, up to you. It won't interfere with the workings of the accordion if I'm not mistaken.

A small example:

```
**html**

<html><body><select id="theList" onchange="showId();"><option>opt1</option><option>opt2</option></select></body></html>

**js**

<script>function showId() { var list = getElementById("theList"); alert(list.options[selectedIndex].value); </script>
```

Hope this clarifies what I mean a bit.